# Retained size calculation including stack frame variables?

Tags: netbeans, jvm-hotspot, hprof

I've found a ton of questions on "retained size" and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3635866/785663) seems to be:

> The retained size for an object is the quantity of memory this objects preserves from garbage collection.

Now, I've been working on programmatic computation of the retained size in a `hprof` file (as defined [here](https://java.net/downloads/heap-snapshot/hprof-binary-format.html)), using the [Netbeans profiler library](http://hg.netbeans.org/profiler-main/file/37ef0296e299/lib.profiler/src/org/netbeans/lib/profiler/heap) (the retained size calculation is done in `HprofHeap.java`). Works just fine (sorry, used kotlin for brevity):

```
val heap: Heap = HeapFactory.createHeap(myHeap.toFile())
val threadClass: JavaClass = heap.getJavaClassByName("java.lang.Thread")
val instanceFilter = { it: Instance -> threadClass == it.getJavaClass() }
val sizeMap = heap.allInstances
            .filter { instanceFilter(it) }
            .toMap({ findThreadName(it) /* not shown */ }, { it.retainedSize })
```

What I noticed when the `sizeMap` had only marginal numbers of retained sizes is that Netbeans computes retained sizes only for objects that are *not* on the stack. So local variables (allocated on the stack) assigned to the `Thread` would *not* be included in the retained size.

My question is: is there a way to make the netbeans library consider the stack elements as dependent objects the way for example the Yourkit Profiler does it's calculation? How would I go about adding such a feature if the answer to the previous question is "no"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of digging found that the JVM heap dumper creates an entry of type `ROOT JAVA FRAME` for a stack local variable (compare [VM_HeapDumper::do_thread](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/17981445/)). Since I can grep for that in the heap, here's what I did:

```
val threadClass: JavaClass = heap.getJavaClassByName("java.lang.Thread")

val keyTransformer = { it: Instance -> findThreadName(it) }
val instanceFilter = { it: Instance -> it.getJavaClass() == threadClass }

val stackLocals = heap.gcRoots
        .filter { it.kind == GCRoot.JAVA_FRAME }
        .groupBy { (it as JavaFrameGCRoot).threadGCRoot }

val sizeMap = heap.allInstances
      .filter { instanceFilter(it) }
      .toMap(
          { keyTransformer(it) }, 
          { 
              val locals = stackLocals[heap.getGCRoot(it)]
              val localSize = locals!!.sumBy { it.instance.retainedSize.toInt() }
              it.retainedSize + localSize
          })

return Report(
        sizeMap.values.sum(),
        sizeMap.keys.size.toLong(),
        sizeMap.maxBy { it.value }?.let { it.toPair() } ?: ("n/a" to 0L))
```

This solution is based on finding the GC root for each thread (should be the `Thread` itself), then sort to the stored gc root of the `JAVA FRAME` (the thread [= GC root] id is part of the stored entry data).

There's still a slight difference compared to the values from Yourkit, probably due to me missing `ROOT JNI LOCAL` entities, but it's close enough for me.